# Centering horizontally in a <div>

Tags: css

I know there are a bunch of answers on here for this topic and believe me I have tried them but I must be stupid lol, my center is always off to the right. There must be something here I am missing and do not understand. If someone would please take the time to tell me why this isn't correctly centered I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<title>Company Name</title>
</head>

<div id="page">
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Company Name</h1>
<p>Company Slogan Here.</p>
</div>
<div class="navbar"><ul id="navlist"><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="index.html">News</a></li><li><a href="index.html">Downloads</a></li><li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li><li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li></ul></div>
<h1>Bob's Bar</h1>
<p>Menu Items</p>
<ul><li>Pizza</li><li>Beer</li><li>Wings</li></ul>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

CSS CODE

```
html{
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

#page{
 box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px #888888;
 background-color: white;
}

#header{
 padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar{
 background-color: #CD0000;
 color: white;
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
 border: 1px solid #CD0000;
}

#navlist{
 text-align: center;
}

#navlist li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
}

#navlist a{
color: white;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `margin`/`padding` on `#navlist` and `#navlist li`? (Haven't tried, but that's what my best guess is just by glancing at it.)

Comment: Also uh...you seem to have a `<body>` nested inside a `<div>`. (Which isn't allowed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your divs to within the body. It's not valid HTML to have divs outside of the body.

Your problem with the off to the right center is because the browser adds a left padding to `<ul>`'s by default, so you need to zero that to get it centered:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evFv7/)

```
#navlist{
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

You might be interested in using a [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) which removes default browser styling.

Comment: HA!! Thank you so very much! That was indeed the issue, I feel really stupid having read about that for two days and no where did I find mention of the browser adding padding to the left of a <ul> however I did suspect such since when I aligned it to the left there was indeed padding I was just unaware of how to fix it I guess.. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, put your first `<div>` inside the `<body>`

```
<body>
<div id="page">
...
</div>
</body>
```

Have you read up on W3Schools pages [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)?

Comment: I was not aware of that rule, however thank you for letting me know, I have moved my first div into the body however the alignment issues remain..